# jOOQ - CTE and INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, jooq

In PostgreSQL, it is possible to have an `INSERT` query into a `WITH` clause:

```
with a as (
    insert into table(...) values(...) returning *
)
select a.*
from a
```

Does jOOQ support this? It seems that only `WITH` + `SELECT` is supported?

**update**

The class `WithAsStep` only supports a select, but the class `WithStep` seems to support all queries. How does the `context.with(CommonTableExpression<?>...)` (which returns a `WithStep`) construction works? I cannot find anything useful in the documentation.

Comment: FYI, `WITH` + `DELETE` and `UPDATE` is also supported by PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible with jOOQ 3.6 because the type returned by `INSERT .. RETURNING` is not a subtype of `Select<?>`, which would be required to put it in jOOQ's [`WithAsStep.as()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/WithAsStep.html#as-org.jooq.Select-) method. There is a feature request [#4474](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4474) to enhance `WithAsStep.as()` to accept `ResultQuery`, but still, the `INSERT .. RETURNING` statement would first need to implement that as well.

I'm afraid, there's no easy workaround for this. Also, in jOOQ 3.6, CTE with DML (`DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`) is not yet supported. The relevant feature request is [#3174](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3174)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! You can consider this as an answer to your https://twitter.com/JavaOOQ/status/634688927752953856 question ;). Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinDeGrote: Good point, although I cannot promise that this can be done in 3.x without breaking backwards-compatibility... It would be a shame, though, really nice PostgreSQL feature!

Comment: No problem if it is not possible! I am already more than happy with the current possibilities. I wish I could convince my colleagues to ditch their fancy ORMs :).